# Default initialization of class data members in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm confused about the default initialization of the class data members. Here is the sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
  int i;
  A() {}
};

A a1;
A aa1[3];
std::vector<A> av1(3);

int main()
{
  A a2;
  A aa2[3];
  std::vector<A> av2(3);
  std::cout << a1.i << " " << a2.i << std::endl;          // 0         undefined
  std::cout << aa1[0].i << " " << aa2[0].i << std::endl;  // 0         undefined
  std::cout << av1[0].i << " " << av2[0].i << std::endl;  // undefined undefined
}
```

In the code above, only `a1.i` and `aa1[0~2].i` are initialized to 0, while others are uninitialized. I don't know why that happened.

To be specific, what I already know from *C++ Primer* is that:

- The process of initialization is:

  - `a1` and `a2` are *default initialized*.
  - every element of `aa1` and `aa2` are *default initialized*.
  - every element of `av1` and `av2` are *value initialized*.
- The process of *default initialize* is:

  - check if the variable is *built-in type* or *class type*.
  - for *built-in type*, if the variable is outside any function body, then it is initialized to 0, else the value is undefined.
  - for *class type*, if the class has default ctor, then that is called, else it is a compile error.
- The process of *value initialize* is:

  - check if the variable is *built-in type* or *class type*.
  - for *built-in type*, it is initialized to 0.
  - for *class type*, it is *default initialized*. (Which I think means if the class has default ctor, then that is called, else it is a compile error.)

So when the ctor `A::A()` is called, how is the data member `A::i` initialized (I guess it is default initialized)? And why are only `a1.i` and `aa1[0~2].i` initialized to 0, while others are uninitialized?

Comment: You can't conclude from an output of 0 that the variable was "initialized to 0". It might be uninitialized and that memory location happened to contain `0`. More importantly, outputting uninitialized variable causes the whole program to have undefined behaviour so you cannot really draw any solid conclusions from the output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> when the ctor A::A() is called, how the data member A::i initialized

If no initializer is provided, the rules of default initialization apply. Your constructor does no initialization of `A::i` so it's left uninitialized; it's value is indeterminate. No doubt about that. Excerpt from the [documentation on default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization):

> If T is a class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list. The constructor selected (which is one of the default constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new object.

---

> why only a1.i and aa1[0~2].i are initialized to 0, while others are uninitialized?

The global data memory is initialized to zero i.e. the whole section is zeroed out and so you see global `A::i`s initialized to `0`. Note that the constructor would not be doing this. Excerpt from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization):

> **Static initialization**
>
> [...]
>
> 2) For all other non-local static and thread-local variables, [Zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) takes place. In practice, variables that are going to be zero-initialized are placed in the .bss segment of the program image, which occupies no space on disk, and is zeroed out by the OS when loading the program.

However, for the `vector`, the `vector` itself is in the non-local static memory while its elements are allocated in free store (heap) and hence their members are uninitialized too.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, much clear now :) BTW, when I read the wiki about [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), there is a mark *(until C++11)* beside some paragraphs, does it means these paragraphs are valid before and include C++11 but will be deprecated  after C++11?

Comment: It means the para holds till C++03, the standard before C++11, and not for C++11 and onwards (like C++17, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Global (both static and exported) variables are zero-initialized (in practice, on usual platforms, they are in memory are which is filled with zeros at program start), if they are not explicitly initialized and don't have a constructor.

Items  of vector are default-initialized, when you use the constructor you are using in your code.

For a vector class object, both mean a constructor call. But for integers, first means initialized to zero, while latter means initialized with indeterminate value. So the plain int variables in your code are zero-initialized, but the ints in the vector are default initialized.

Some links for reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Answer (score 1):

You declare a constructor for `A`, so there is no default initialization of `i`; that's your responsibility in the constructor.  The global variables get initial values of 0 because they're global.  All globals are initialized to 0 if they aren't given an initial value by some means.

The local variables and vectors get random data because that's what's in the memory on the stack (for locals) or heap (for the allocated memory that the vector uses) that is being used by those `A` instances.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, will `A::i` be initialized to 0 if I left out the constructor and use the default constructor that the compiler generated?

Comment: `A::i` will be initialized to zero only if you do it in the constructor, otherwise it's always left uninitialized.

Comment: @legends2k it's not quite so simple: the vector elements are constructed as if by `new(location) A()`. If `A` has a user-defined constructor that doesn't initialize `i` then this means `i` will be uninitialized; but otherwise `A` is an aggregate and so `i` will be set to `0`

Comment: @M.M If _`A` is an aggregate_, you mean we've a vector of aggregates? Then, yes, all elements of the aggregate would be value initialized. I felt that aggregate initialization was a corner case and didn't want to confuse the OP with it.

Answer (score 1):

The initialization of an object of class type is controlled by the class, and this process is done **recursively**. Take your sample code for example, the initialization of `i` is controlled by `A`. Since no constructor is provided, the synthesized default constructor will be used. And since no in-class initializers are provided, every member of `A` is default initialized, again, the default initialization rule is queried. The built-in type `i` will be left uninitialized. If `A` contains a member `s` of type `string`, then the default initialization of `s` is controlled by the `string` class (**the recursive rule takes place**). In this case, `s` will be initialized to an empty string.